# object type of html markups that passed as javascript function parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to javascript and react. In React, we see the following sample code:

```
     ReactDOM.render(
      <h1> Hello, world! </h1>,
      document.getElementById('example')
```

Here ReactDOM.render accetps  '<h1> Hello, world! </h1>' as the first parameter.

I tried the following test code, the alert box shows '[object Object]'. If I use 'typeof var1' for alert(...), I will only get 'object'. What is the exact type of this object? How can I debug and view the detailed info of it?

```
    function mytest(var1, var2) {
        alert(var1);
        document.getElementById('example2').appendChild(var1);
    }

    mytest(<h1>hello</h1>, <h2>world</h2>);
```

Comment: Did you try alert(typeof var1); ??? You may also loop in var1 to see the content of the object.

Comment: alert(typeof var1) returns  'object'.

Answer (score 1):

Your [JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) code when transpiled to plain javascript (using Babel) looks like this:

```
function mytest(var1, var2) {
        alert(var1);
        document.getElementById('example2').appendChild(var1);
}

mytest(React.createElement(
        'h1',
        null,
        'hello'
), React.createElement(
        'h2',
        null,
        'world'
));
```

So as you can see `var1` is actually a product of [`React.createElement`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html) function and it's [ReactElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/glossary.html).

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. You'll get a stringed version of your react element. Keep in mind it won't come back as a traditional js object, like {}. It's probably a react element, so stringifying it will take some doing. What I show below should give you what react actually does with that element.

```
alert(React.renderToString(var1));
```

Comment: I might miss something. I got  " embedded:5 Uncaught TypeError: React.renderToString is not a function" error.

Comment: I'm assuming you are including React in your page. I might have misunderstood your setup.